# iOS: pushViewController freezes the app

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am a new iOS developer working on some legacy code. I learned from the code that to launch a new screen, I can do:

```
SomeViewController* view = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
[view release];
```

I have a screen B is launched from screen A. I need to further launch a screen C from screen B. The flow is A -> B -> C. when I do B->C, the app freezes and the screen looks like this:

[image]

However when I do A->C, it's working perfectly. Has anyone seen this before? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you profiled your app during these transition? Anything looks abnormal in instruments?

Comment: Please show the code that does `A -> B -> C`

Comment: The information you've given so far is unsufficient to solve the problem. Try running "Analyze" and running the code with zombie enabled. Off-topic comment: the name `view` is bad: a viewController is not a `UIView` and this is important...

Comment: Also, you should post the code initializing SomeViewController

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what the true problem may be without seeing more code. However, I do notice two problems:

1. It is typical to see a navigation bar being displayed when you are pushing viewcontrollers onto the UINavigationController stack. I don't see a navigation bar in your screen shot. You may need to embed a UINavigationController.
2. This was somewhat mentioned already in one of the comments. Pushing a UIView onto a UIViewController stack is an undifined action--you should be pushing a UIViewController. For example:

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewControllerForViewC animated:YES];